# How to use Shared Preferences to save data selected on Spinner and from checked Radio Button

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save into shared preference object what the user selects from Spinner and also save which radio button was checked (positive or negative value). THEN display or retrieve data from shared preference object.

Here is how my onCreate method looks like:

```
public class ShoulderActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {                   
// The attribute used to store the value of the special test id <= used in sharedPreferences                 
    int selectedPosition;              

// The attribute used to store the value (positive or negative) that correspond to the special test id <= used in sharedPreferences         
    EditText STValue;              
    TextView STNameTextView, STValueTextView;              

public static final String DEFAULT = "N/A";     

@Override     
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{         
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.shoulder_layout);              
    Spinner shoulderSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.shoulder_spinner);              

    //Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner     
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> shoulderAdapter = ArrayAdapter                .createFromResource(this, R.array.shoulder_tests,                          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);              

    //Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears        
    shoulderAdapter            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);              

    //Apply the adapter to the spinner        
    shoulderSpinner.setAdapter(shoulderAdapter);               
    shoulderSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);               

}//END onCreate
```

And below I wrote add() method to save into shared preference object:

```
public void add(View view)
{              
    //User SharedPreferences to save the value per special test         
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("STData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);              
    //to edit the data or add data inside my file "STData"          
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();              
    //Store the values in my file "STData"         

    // ******** pull up the name of the test from ONITEM selected on SPINNER **********             
    //editor.putString("specialTestName", STName.getText().toString() );         

    int selectedPosition = shoulderSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()           
    editor.putInt("specialTestName", selectedPosition);         

    editor.commit();              

    //**************************************         

    // get this value from the Radio Button *****************              
    RadioButton posValuerb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.positiveId);              
    // Save the test value; if positive test radio button is checked means test is positive and vice-versa         
    editor.putBoolean("STValue", posValuerb1.isChecked());                   
    //To confirm the changes or to save them         
    editor.commit();     }
```

And below my display() method to retrieve and display data from the shared preference object:

```
    // Method to Display special tests performed in the STData file     
public void display(View view)
{                   
    // User SharedPreferences to save the value per special name    
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("STData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);              
    shoulderSpinner.setSelection(sharedPref.getInt("spinnerSelection",0));         

    //save special test Value in String 'testValue' <= entered by the PT         
    String testValue = sharedPref.getString("STValue", DEFAULT);                   

    // DISPlAY THE VALUES ON THE SCREEN OF ACTIVITY !!!!

         // Test Name         
    STNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.STView3);          
    STNameTextView.setText(testName);              // Name of the Special Test          
    STValueTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.STView4);          
    STValueTextView.setText(testValue);     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly misunderstanding the way SharedPreference class works.
Since you decided to persist a int value with the key "specialTestName"
you should retrieve it as follows, to obtain the saved int:

```
int selectedPosition = sharedPrefObj.getInt("specialTestName", DEFAULTINT);
```

Also, what you are saving from the checkbox is a boolean value, so you cannot try to retrieve as String.

```
boolean checkValue = sharedPrefObj.getBoolean("STValue", DEFAULTBOOLEAN);
```

Btw I highly recommend you to create a class that interacts directly with the SharedPreference instead of use it directly from the Activity/Fragment.

Hope this helps you.